# Error on creating minified css with grunt-contrib-cssmin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I have an issue when I try to create minified css with `grunt-contrib-cssmin.`
SourceMap`on`cssmin.js` is set as false and I can't find why I keep getting this error message.

What should I do with this `./source-map/source-map-generator" error?`

**Error message**

```
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module './source-map/source-map-generator'
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    cssmin: {
        target: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'css',
                src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
                dest: 'css',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'css',
                src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
                dest: 'mw/css/',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        cleancss: {
            files: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
            tasks: 'cssmin'
        },
    },
});

// Load the plugin
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: try to remove your `node_modules` folder and re-install your dependencies with `npm install`. And try to re-run your task

Comment: I am new as a web developer and even though the problem look silly, you gave a right solution and I resolved it.
Thank you, @LouisBarranqueiro.

Comment: Good news. I'm going to add it as an anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove your `node_modules` folder and re-install your dependencies with `npm install`. And try to re-run your task